# Existence of a particular sequence of sets for a probability measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ and let $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ be such that $\mu(A)>0$.

> Under what conditions on $\mu$ will there exist a sequence of sets $B_n \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\mu(A \triangle B_n) >0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\mu(A \triangle B_n) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

It is not diffuclt to come with a particular $\mu$ and $A$ for which the requirement is fullfilled. For example, assume that $\mu$ has Lebesgue density and $A=[0, 1]$. Take $B_n = [1/n, 1]$. Then the sequence of sets $A \triangle B_n = [0, 1/n)$ decreases to $\{0\}$, which is a null set.

Can something similar be down for an arbitrary set $A$ which is not a null set?

What if $\mu$ does not have a Lebesgue density?

Comment: really depend on context... for example, if $\mu=\delta _0$ the Dirac measure at $0$, such set will never exist...

Comment: @Surb Can't we always say that $\vert  \text{supp}(\mu)\cap A \vert>\infty$ must hold?

Answer (score 1):

If you can do it with $A = \varnothing$, then you can do it in general.

Assume there exist $F_n$ with $\mu(F_n) \to 0$ and $\mu(F_n)>0$.  So, given $A$, let $B_n = A\triangle F_n$.  Then
$$
A\triangle B_n = A\triangle(A\triangle F_n) = (A\triangle A)\triangle F_n = F_n .
$$